# 301 Redirect using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

I had a system migration on my website and approximately 400 links got permanently changed. I'm using the following `Redirect` in `.htaccess` file for redirecting old links to new links.

`Redirect 301 /old-folder/old-product.html /new-folder/new-product.html`

I'm planning to do the similar thing to all 400 links.

**My problem:** Since I'm all having these Redirect statements in one .htaccess file, will there be any performance issues? Is it okay to add so many `Redirect` statements in one .htaccess file? Are there any side effects?

**Note:** there is no fixed pattern in the old and new links so I can't use `RewriteRule`.

Comment: 400! I wouldnt think so... looking at the documentation there is a performance difference in using htaccess overrides but I don't think it would make much difference.